# Changing the naming of a Tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I attempted to edit the question here [Can X-rays be used for communication?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/can-x-rays-be-used-for-communication) to have the proper naming for the Tag "x-ray", but it failed and told me to raise it on meta.

Can an moderator edit the tag, or at least add x-ray with xray as a synonym.